# PySpark job seems to be stuck while materializing RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a SparkJob that starts off by creating a pairwise score matrix between N items. Though intensive this is pretty fast up-to about 20K elements after which it seems to get stuck for a very long time. The last log line that I saw over multiple attempts was 'cleaned accumulator ' I've attached the code block below to repro the issue with a randomly created dataset of 50K elements. The cartesian product is quite fast and a count on the resulting RDD returns in a couple of minutes (2.5 billion rows) but the second count gets stuck for over two hours with no progress updates in the logs or the Spark Jobs UI. I have a cluster of 15 EC2 M3.2xLarge nodes. How can I understand what's happening here and what can be done to speed this up?

```
import random
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, SQLContext
import math
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.types import Row
sc=SparkContext(appName='kmedoids_test')
sqlContext=HiveContext(sc)
n=50000
A = [random.normalvariate(0, 1) for i in range(n)]
B = [random.normalvariate(1, 1) for i in range(n)]
C = [random.normalvariate(-1, 0.5) for i in range(n)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(zip(A,B,C), ["A","B","C"])
f = lambda x, y : math.pow((x.A - y.A), 2) + math.pow((x.B - y.B), 2) +    math.pow((x.C - y.C), 2)
schema  = StructType([StructField("row_id", LongType(), False)] +       df.schema.fields[:])
no_of_cols=len(df.columns)
rdd_zipped_with_index=df.rdd.zipWithIndex()
reconstructed_rdd = rdd_zipped_with_index.map(lambda x: [x[1]]+list(x[0][0:no_of_cols]))
indexed_df=reconstructed_rdd.toDF(schema)
indexed_rdd = indexed_df.rdd
sc._conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold","-1") #turning off broadcast join
rdd_cartesian_prod = indexed_rdd.cartesian(indexed_rdd)
print "----------Count in self-join--------------- {0}".format(rdd_cartesian_prod.count()) #this returns quickly in about 160s
ScoreVec = Row("head_id","tail_id","score")
output_rdd = rdd_cartesian_prod.map(lambda x :   ScoreVec(float(x[0].row_id), float(x[1].row_id), float(f(x[0], x[1]))))
print "-----------Count after scoring---------------  {0}".format(output_rdd.count()) #gets stuck here for a LONG time
output_df = output_rdd.toDF() #does not get here
```

Comment: "cleaned accumulator" is just a line that Spark spits out constantly if you don't tell it to be less verbose.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to [lazy evaluation](https://www.mapr.com/blog/5-minute-guide-understanding-significance-apache-spark)

> Spark is the same. It waits until you’re done giving it operators, and only when you ask it to give you the final answer does it evaluate, and it always looks to limit how much work it has to do.

The number of rows after the cartesian product is going to be `indexed_rdd.count()^2`. Spark does not actually need to generate all of these rows to know how many there will be. Although the number of rows is the same in `output_rdd.count()`, Spark is actually processing all of the data and mapping over it before counting. That's why this task is taking so much longer. To prove that this is what's happening, you can try `indexed_rdd.cache().count()`. Caching prior to counting will force data processing (and saving the result in memory) and will take a long time.

Comment: Thanks David. As you suggested, I tried rdd_cartesian_prod.cache().count() to force processing of the self join RDD. Still finishes in a minute, while the rest of the job takes over 45 minutes for a 30k dataset. How can I speed this up? Will increasing parallelism be counter productive and end up shuffling more?